# web api attribute routing without convention based routing

Tags: routes, asp.net-web-api2, owin, asp.net-web-api-routing, attributerouting

I have web api(owin hosted) and MVC project in a single solution. My routing for web api works if i have convention based but attribute routing is not working. To test attribute routing, I removed default conventioned based configuration for my web api routing. I have following entries

**startup.cs**

```
public partial class Startup
 {

   public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
   { 
    var config = new HttpConfiguration();
     app.Map("/api", inner =>
        {
            ConfigureWebApi(config);
            inner.UseWebApi(config);
        });
   }

   public void ConfigureWebApi(HttpConfiguration config)
   {
        // Web API configuration and services

        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
   } // no default convention based routing
```

**ProductsController.cs**

```
public class ProductsController : ApiController
 {
    [Route("api/products")]
    public IHttpActionResult Get()
    {

    }

     [Route("api/products/TopCategories"),HttpGet]
    public IHttpActionResult GetTopCategories()
    {

    }
 }
```

I dont want to be dependent on MVC routing for web api, but just in case if anything is missing here please let me know.

**routeconfig.cs**

```
public class RouteConfig
 {
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

**Global.asax.cs**

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        //web api routes from startup.cs
        //GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
    }
}
```

I used **routeprefix** but removed for testing purposes.
I think below both Url's should work but for some reason they are not and I'm getting 404 error.

1)http://localhost:xxxx/api/products
2)http://localhost:xxxx/api/products/TopCategories.

Based on stack trace, for some reason, i think my MVC routing is handing "/api" routes( i may be wrong).

```
   System.Web.HttpException (0x80004005): The controller for path    '/api/products' was not found or does not implement IController.
   at System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.GetControllerInstance(RequestContext   requestContext, Type controllerType)
   at System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.CreateController(RequestContext requestContext, String controllerName)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.ProcessRequestInit(HttpContextBase httpContext, IController& controller, IControllerFactory& factory)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContextBase httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback cb, Object extraData)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

Comment: Does it look like you would be adding the constant string "api" to the uri twice? Once in the app.map and again in the route attribute. Have you tried api/api/products?

Comment: you are correct bill, api/api/products worked. I fixed my attributes and removed api from it. thanks once again.